# Java documentation -- missing methods?

Tags: java

The method `init()` of [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) isn't in the Java documentation.

Neither is `addUnstarted()` of [`ThreadGroup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html).

What am I missing ???

Comment: Why would you publish non-accessible methods?

Comment: to see what they're doing. that's the whole point of looking up the source.

Comment: private methods are there for implementation details, you can't call a private method so there is no reason you would need to know what they do.  They might be removed from a future version or not exist in a different JVM.

Comment: lol. just when I was thinking why some algs or stuff on the native methods aren't there.

Answer (score 4):

These methods are private and package private, respectively, so they are not publicly documented in the standard Javadoc. However, you can find the documentation in the OpenJDK source itself:

- `init()` in `Thread` is private. [It's documentation can be found here.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.init%28java.lang.ThreadGroup%2Cjava.lang.Runnable%2Cjava.lang.String%2Clong%29)
- `addUnstarted()` in `ThreadGroup` is package private. [It's documentation can be found here.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/ThreadGroup.java#ThreadGroup.addUnstarted%28%29)

Comment: They **are** documented but the proper documentation is not publicly available. Instead, check the source code of the class. E.g.: [`Thread#init`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.init%28java.lang.ThreadGroup%2Cjava.lang.Runnable%2Cjava.lang.String%2Clong%29).